# Filter array of objects by nested array of object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, filter

Suppose I have an array of objects, each of which contains a nested array of objects `likes`:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Lorem',
    private: false,
    likes: [
      { id: 01, username: 'mike' },
      { id: 02, username: 'john' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Ipsum',
    private: true,
    likes: [
      { id: 03, username: 'steve' },
      { id: 04, username: 'mike' },
      { id: 05, username: 'sara' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Dolor',
    private: false,
    likes: [
      { id: 06, username: 'brad' },
      { id: 07, username: 'cameron' },
      { id: 08, username: 'liam' }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I filter the outer array by the username value inside its items nested array? Let's say output the items that contains in its inner arrays objects with property `username: 'mike'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter by looking into the nested array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: 'Lorem', private: false, likes: [{ id: 01, username: 'mike' }, { id: 02, username: 'john' }] }, { id: 2, title: 'Ipsum', private: true, likes: [{ id: 03, username: 'steve' }, { id: 04, username: 'mike' }, { id: 05, username: 'sara' }] }, { id: 3, title: 'Dolor', private: false, likes: [{ id: 06, username: 'brad' }, { id: 07, username: 'cameron' }, { id: 08, username: 'liam' }] }],
    result = data.filter(({ likes }) => likes.some(({ username }) => username === 'mike'));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter and some functions:

```js
const input = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Lorem",
    private: false,
    likes: [{
      id: 1,
      username: "mike"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      username: "john"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Ipsum",
    private: true,
    likes: [{
        id: 3,
        username: "steve"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        username: "mike"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        username: "sara"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Dolor",
    private: false,
    likes: [{
        id: 6,
        username: "brad"
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        username: "cameron"
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        username: "liam"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const criteria = {
  username: "mike"
};

const result = input.filter(x =>
  x.likes.some(y => y.username === criteria.username)
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'map' function to filter the internal array

```
const data = [
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Lorem',
    private: false,
    likes: [
      { id: 1, username: 'mike' },
      { id: 2, username: 'john' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Ipsum',
    private: true,
    likes: [
      { id: 3, username: 'steve' },
      { id: 4, username: 'mike' },
      { id: 5, username: 'sara' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Dolor',
    private: false,
    likes: [
      { id: 6, username: 'brad' },
      { id: 7, username: 'cameron' },
      { id: 8, username: 'liam' }
    ]
  }
]

const res = data.map( item => {
  let likes = item.likes.filter( user => user.username === 'mike')
  if(likes.length > 0 ) {
    item.likes = likes 
    return item
  }
  return null 
}).filter(item => item !== null )

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` and `find` in likes.

```js
const filter = (data, name) =>
  data.filter(({ likes }) => likes.find(({ username }) => username === name));

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Lorem",
    private: false,
    likes: [
      { id: 01, username: "mike" },
      { id: 02, username: "john" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Ipsum",
    private: true,
    likes: [
      { id: 03, username: "steve" },
      { id: 04, username: "mike" },
      { id: 05, username: "sara" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Dolor",
    private: false,
    likes: [
      { id: 06, username: "brad" },
      { id: 07, username: "cameron" },
      { id: 08, username: "liam" },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(filter(data, "mike"));
console.log(filter(data, "blah"));
```